# What is the Inverse of Idle in /proc/stat?

Tags: linux, proc

`/proc/stat/` includes the following fields:

```
"user",
"nice",
"system",
"idle",
"iowait",
"irq",
"softirq",
"guest",
"guest_nice",
```

Which subset of those fields + idle accounts for 100% CPU? Is there some overlap, or should the total of all fields always be 100% of CPU time?

Answer (score 1):

It should be that system + user + idle = 100% (those are about CPU time). As long as you have got 1 CPU only (lately unlikely, even my cellphone has two cores ;-). The `sar(1)` command (on Fedora part of the sysstat package) summarizes this kind of data, it's manpage might be of further help.

Answer (score 0):

I always use user + system + nice + idle + iowait == 100%.

On some systems, there's also "steal" which is typically if the OS is running in a VM.